# How to make Java program to pick classes from Specific Jar?

Tags: java

I have a Java program that uses StringUtils jar from apache commons. We have commons-lang 2.4.jar which contains that StringUtils class file. Currently we are trying to migrate our application from WAS 6.1 to WAS 7. When we try to do so, we have a StringUtils class file which comes as a part of WAS 7's JPA plugin. In our project's build path we have given WAS 7 Libraries also along with the places where it has to look for class files. The StringUtils class file in Commons-lang2.4 jar and WAS 7's JPA plugin's jar are of two different versions. Workspace by default takes the WAS 7's JPA plugin. Since our code already uses the commons-lang2.4.jar, we are facing certain compilation errors. So now I need to override this behavior of my workspace (rather R

Answer (score 3):

IBM WAS StringUtils class is `com.ibm.btt.utils.StringUtils`, Apache Commons class is `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`. If you insert both, you have to use the full-qualified name of the class. If you only import the Apache commons one in your code, it should only use that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, java class loader searches for specific class through all of entries of current CLASSPATH, and picks up first class found.
So, if you want to use StringUtils from apache commons, you have to place commons-lang jar file first in CLASSPATH. This should solve your problem.

Comment: While true in general, this answer has no meaning in WebSphere. WebSphere has a hierarchy of classloaders, each with their own classpath. In WebSphere, you talk about class resolution order wherein you configure if classes should be resolved by searching the application classloader first and then moving up the chain, or starting with the server top-level classloader and then working down the chain, searching the application classloader last.